# How do I find the key of maximum element in a dictionary in Python language?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a problem since 10 days I tried to find the solution on books and internet but could not find it. Here there is an example:

```
animals = { 'a': ['lion'], 'b': ['baboon'], 'c': ['goat']}
animals['d'] = ['donkey']
animals['d'].append('elephant')
animals['d'].append('swan')
```

and I have to write a method `largest` to find out the key being associated to the longest list. In the example the output should be

```
largest(animals)
'd'
```

Comment: Can you more specific with regards to the definition of 'largest' in your question? I guess you want the key associated with the list of maximum length in the dictionary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `max()` built-in with custom function used for comparisons between keys.

```
animals = { 'a': ['lion'], 'b': ['baboon'], 'c': ['goat']}
animals['d'] = ['donkey']
animals['d'].append('elephant')
animals['d'].append('swan')

largest = max(animals, key=lambda k: len(animals[k]))
```

Using `key` argument to `max` function allows to change a criteria by which elements are compared.
In this case *keys* of dictionary are compared according to length of list stored under this key in dictionary `animals`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your so quick answer. Actually I am a noice programmer in Python not professional. I got my answer but how come it come here I don't know. May be in future when I learn more Python then I shall know.

Answer (score 1):

Split the dictionary into 2 lists of keys and values, if your dictionary is not very large. This can be very efficient method.
Then, you can find the max element using the `max()` function.

```
def largest(animals):
    keys = list(animals.keys())
    vals = list(animals.values())
    return keys[vals.index(max(vals))]
```